# LARK parsing error for hex number

Tags: parsing, python-3.6, lark-parser

I try to parse hex number with:
hex_number : "0x" HEXDIGIT+ and with 0xA as input, and it always throws me an error, A is unexpected token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little example that won't throw you any error:

```
from lark import Lark


if __name__ == "__main__":
    grammar = """
        start: hex_number
        hex_number : "0x" HEXDIGIT+
        %import common.HEXDIGIT
        %import common.WS
        %ignore WS
    """

    parser = Lark(grammar, start='start')
    tree = parser.parse("    0xA    ")
```